# Is it possible to use delayed inserts and retrieve the ID for follow-up queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-insert-id

I am building an analytics tool for the website and to simplify my sequence of INSERTs looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO visits (id, page, url) VALUES (null, 'http://...', '...');
INSERT INTO params (visit_id, name, val) VALUES (123, 'page', 'product');
INSERT INTO params (visit_id, name, val) VALUES (123, 'product_id', '7');
```

So in other words there is a central table and other tables that link to it using the ID of the main INSERT. I want to convert these INSERTs to DELAYED INSERTs so that users don't suffer in case the database server responsible for storing analytics data gets overloaded and can't handle all the writes anymore. However since DELAYED INSERT doesn't allow to use LAST_INSERT_ID(), I am not sure how to maintain the above relation between tables.

Is there some easy way to do it other than generating your own ID and assigning unique index to it and then using it to join tables if necessary.

Comment: You can write a MySQL function that takes parameters and does all of your inserts for you into different tables. Then I'm pretty sure you can run that function on a delay so the user doesn't have to wait for it, but all of the inserts would still happen together so you could maintain your relations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in an `INSERT DELAYED` statement. You just can't use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the id for the delayed statement. Instead, it will return the value for the previous (non-delayed) insert.

This will work:

```
INSERT INTO visits (id, page, url) VALUES (null, 'http://...', '...');
INSERT DELAYED INTO params (visit_id, name, val) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'page', 'product');
INSERT DELAYED INTO params (visit_id, name, val) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'product_id', '7');
```

However, `INSERT DELAYED` is deprecated in the latest version of MySQL. Consider a different approach.